# Any equivalent to vmtools to install on Centos 6.6 KVM (Centos)Guest?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6

When creating a Linux VM in ESX, I would typically use the vSphere Client to mark the VM for an installation of vmtools.  vmtools is kept on the Server, installed at the next boot of the VM, and allows me shutdown or reboot the VM gracefully from the vSphere Client interface (plus other benefits).

On a fresh Centos 6.6 server, I've installed qemu-guest-agent and qemu-kvm-tools thinking that would cover things.  But from the virt-manager interface, I can't shutdown a VM (that option in the gui has no effect), and I don't see mention of any tools install option under the VM's "Details".

I'll work with virsh in the future, but assume I'll need something like vmtools in that case too, if I want to gracefully shutdown a VM.

Thanks for any advice....Lyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make shutdown work from outside the guest on CentOS 6, you need to install the `acpid` package and start the `acpid` service.

```
yum install acpid
chkconfig acpid on
service acpid start
```

Comment: Yes, once you told me what to look for, I find lots of hits.  Thanks...